# pandas DataFrame extracting coordinate information from a column and forming a list of lat & lon pairs in a list

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a text/tuple column as show in the attached screenshot. [image]

Below is also an example of the data in the column:

```
Colum title - POLYGON_WKT_TEXT
POLYGON ( (-105.01884585094353 39.62333777125623, 
        -105.01851820478282 39.62333686626711,
        -105.0185192106112 39.62315273546345,
        -105.01888004910847 39.6231533822067,
        -105.01888071966073 39.62322879067289,
        -105.01884585094353 39.62322827417681,
        -105.01884585094353 39.62333777125623) )
POLYGON ((-106.83036867299995 39.19331872400005, 
        -106.83027684299998 39.19329631000005,
        -106.83034537399999 39.19313263400005,
        -106.83060769199994 39.19318738000004, 
        -106.83056232299998 39.19329573700003, 
        -106.83052058199996 39.19328554900005, 
        -106.83048588899999 39.19336841100005, 
        -106.83036066599999 39.19333784600008, 
        -106.83036867299995 39.19331872400005))
        
        ...
        ...
```

I would like to have this field in the format below:

```
column name - POLYGON_WKT_TXT
[(-105.01884585094353 39.62333777125623), (-105.01851820478282 39.62333686626711), ...(-106.83036867299995 39.19331872400005)]
```

I have so far tried to split on the comma (",") into multiple columns, but the issue is that the length of the values in the column varies ends up not making my solution efficient.

Thanks in advance for your elegant way to solve this task.

Comment: Split looks like the right approach to me. How are you iterating through your df? Some ways are much slower than others.

Comment: Do each of the polygons have the same number of points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if I understand your question, this is very simple
- create dataframe from WKT text provided in question
- from this create a **list** of **tuples**.  This is as simple as using https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.wkt.loads and `exterior.coords`
- have provided output as image as it's not formatting well as markdown

```
import shapely.wkt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"polygon_wkt_txt":["""POLYGON ( (-105.01884585094353 39.62333777125623, 
        -105.01851820478282 39.62333686626711,
        -105.0185192106112 39.62315273546345,
        -105.01888004910847 39.6231533822067,
        -105.01888071966073 39.62322879067289,
        -105.01884585094353 39.62322827417681,
        -105.01884585094353 39.62333777125623) )""",
"""POLYGON ((-106.83036867299995 39.19331872400005, 
        -106.83027684299998 39.19329631000005,
        -106.83034537399999 39.19313263400005,
        -106.83060769199994 39.19318738000004, 
        -106.83056232299998 39.19329573700003, 
        -106.83052058199996 39.19328554900005, 
        -106.83048588899999 39.19336841100005, 
        -106.83036066599999 39.19333784600008, 
        -106.83036867299995 39.19331872400005))"""]})

df["tuple_list"] = df["polygon_wkt_txt"].apply(lambda txt: list(shapely.wkt.loads(txt).exterior.coords))

df
```

[image]